# Search for a list of values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

so i'm trying to do a search into a nested dictionary with a list of values.
My nested dictionary contains per every key the information about different products (for every single key i have one unique product).

Im trying to get just those keys from my dictionary that contains this three words that I have on my list.

The idea is that this search can be flexible in the way that I'm able to change the list adding new words (so the length of my list could change).

For example:

My list of values is:

```
details = ['PARACETAMOL','100','MG']
```

And I have the next dictionary:

```
dict = {{
    1:  'description': 'KITADOL  500  TABL  1 . 00 G x  18 ',
        'key_words': ['KITADOL', '500', 'TABL', '1', '.', '00', 'G', 'x', '18'],
        'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},
    {
    2:  'description': 'ACAMOL GOTAS  100 MG  15 ML x  1  /ML',
        'key_words': ['ACAMOL', 'GOTAS', '100', 'MG', '15', 'ML', 'x', '1', '/ML'],
        'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},
    {   
    3:  'description': 'PANAGESIC GOTAS  100 MG  15 ML x  1 ',
        'key_words': ['PANAGESIC', 'GOTAS', '100', 'MG', '15', 'ML', 'x', '1'],
        'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},
    {
    4:  'description': 'GRIPASAN DIA Y NOC CA.D 12 +CA.N 6  x  18 ',
        'key_words': ['GRIPASAN','DIA','Y','NOC','CA.D','12','+CA.N','6','x','18'],
        'molecule': ['CAFEINA','CLORFENAMINA','PARACETAMOL','PROPIFENAZONA','PSEUDOEFEDRINA']}
    }
```

So i want to get the next keys `3` and `4`.

I wonder if someone could help me or give some ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it might help you find the `keys` you need:

**besides**

- *your dict instruction had some problem with opening bracket `{`.*
- *the result you mentioned wasn't the correct answer*

#### Search Function:

```py
def dict_custom_search(dictt, details):
    keys = []
    for index in range(1, len(dictt)):
        found_counter = 0
        for detail in details:
            if detail in dictt[index]['description'] or detail in dictt[index]['key_words'] or detail in dictt[index]['molecule']:
                found_counter += 1
        if found_counter == len(details):
            keys.append(index)
    return keys
```

#### Input

```py
dictf = {
    1:  {'description': 'KITADOL  500  TABL  1 . 00 G x  18 ',
         'key_words': ['KITADOL', '500', 'TABL', '1', '.', '00', 'G', 'x', '18'],
         'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},

    2: { 'description': 'ACAMOL GOTAS  100 MG  15 ML x  1  /ML',
         'key_words': ['ACAMOL', 'GOTAS', '100', 'MG', '15', 'ML', 'x', '1', '/ML'],
         'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},

    3: { 'description': 'PANAGESIC GOTAS  100 MG  15 ML x  1 ',
         'key_words': ['PANAGESIC', 'GOTAS', '100', 'MG', '15', 'ML', 'x', '1'],
         'molecule': ['PARACETAMOL']},

    4:  {'description': 'GRIPASAN DIA Y NOC CA.D 12 +CA.N 6  x  18 ',
         'key_words': ['GRIPASAN','DIA','Y','NOC','CA.D','12','+CA.N','6','x','18'],
         'molecule': ['CAFEINA','CLORFENAMINA','PARACETAMOL','PROPIFENAZONA','PSEUDOEFEDRINA']}
}

details = ['PARACETAMOL','100','MG']
```

and after calling the function `dict_custom_search(dictf, details)` and pass the parameters you will get a list of found keys.

#### output

```py
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfect.... my mistake with the answer but yes, i was expecting 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this :

```
details = ['PARACETAMOL','100','MG']
[k for k,v in d.items() if all(map(lambda x: x in v["key_words"] + v["molecule"],details))]
```

Result:

```
[2,3]
```

*Attention: *

1. never use dict as variable, this is a reserved word
2. your structure wasn't ok "{"-at the begining was too mutch